# Объявление двумерного вектора

Tags: c++

Я хочу создать вектор векторов, подсмотрела тут, что это можно сделать так, если известен только один размер:

```
vector<vector<T> > b(n, vector<T>());
```

Мне нужно было создать n векторов и положить в некоторые из них элементы (если на вход поступает три числа a, c, r, то b[a][c] = r. А потом я хотела пройтись циклом и вывести все элементы вектора b:

```
  for (const auto& vec : b) {
    if (vec.size()) {
      for (const int elem : vec) {
        cout << elem << ' ';
      }
    }
  }
```

И, конечно, получаю ошибку. Подскажите, пожалуйста, то есть при таком объявлении вектора b он не заполняется векторами? Как тогда можно избежать данной ошибки?

Comment: Заполняется пустыми векторами. И если бы вектор не передавался, было бы так же. И ошибки быть не должно. Если не считать того, что переводы строк тоже надо бы выводить.

Comment: *"И, конечно, получаю ошибку."* - https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Answer (score -1):

> Мне нужно было создать n векторов и положить в некоторые из них
> элементы (если на вход поступает три числа a, c, r, то b[a][c] = r. А
> потом я хотела пройтись циклом и вывести все элементы вектора b

Тут нужно знать 2 числа: наибольшее значение a и наибольшее значение c.

Соответственно, правильная инициализация вектора, выглядела бы как-то так:

```
   vector< vector<T> > matrix( MaxA );
   for (auto &subvector : matrix)
       subvector.resize( MaxC );
```

Где MaxA и MaxC такие, что любой индекс a < MaxA, а любой индекс c < MaxC.

Соответственно, вывод вроде такого:

```
   for (auto& subvector : matrix) {
       for (auto& element : subvector)
           std::cout << element << ' ';
       std::cout << '\n'; // или std::endl
   }
```

Есть и альтернативный вариант (с одним вектором):

```
   vector< T > linear_matrix( MaxA * MaxC );
```

В таком случае, для доступа к тем же элементам, нужно произвести вот такое умножение:

```
   linear_matrix[ a * MaxC + c ] = r;
```

Соответственно вывод, был бы примерно такой:

```
   for (size_t a = 0; a < MaxA; ++ a) {// вместо size_t можно использовать любой целочисленный тип подходящего размера (как знаковый, так и без), лишь бы MaxA и MaxC в него помещались
      for (size_t c = 0; c < MaxA; ++ c)
          std::cout << linear_matrix[ a * MaxC + c ] << ' ';
      std::cout << '\n'; // Тут можно заменить '\n' на std::endl
   }
```